# redirect dynamic url to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, 301-redirect

I am trying to redirect the URL to the corresponding subdomain.

For example:

```
example.com/account/user
example.com/account/user2
```

to

```
user.example.com
user2.example.com
```

I have tried:

```
Redirect /account/user http://user.example.com
```

but this shows the homepage of `example.com` instead of the content of `example.com/account/user`.

At the domain level, I set  `*` as an alias of `example.com`.

Comment: "At the domain level, I set `*` as an alias of `example.com`." - What exactly do you mean by that? Did you create a "wildcard" CNAME record in the DNS? Did you set the `ServerAlias` appropriately? Anything else? How does `user.example.com` route to `example.com/account/user`? It sounds like you are perhaps trying to create the redirect before you've established how the URL routes to the correct place? (Which URL are you _linking_ to?)

Answer (score 1):

Your redirect works as expected. You didn't configure anything that would show something different at `http://user.example.com`, so you should that happen?

Why do you even want to do this? Normally you would redirect `http://user.example.com` to something like `http://example.com/account/user`. Do you want to change your Apache configuration for each new user? Use a script that evaluates the Host header sent by the client?

I think what you want is something like

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}"   "!^www\.example\.com" [NC]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}"   "!^example\.com" [NC]
RewriteRule "^/?(.*)"        "http://www.example.com/account/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1" [L,R,NE]
```

What you say you want is achieved by

```
RewriteRule /account/(.*)     "http://$1.example.com/"
```

But I think what you really want is exactly the reverse.

Comment: i want that every user to have his own subdomain.. redirect url to subdomain and show the content of that url on the subdomain.. rewrite url to subdomain ... is that even possible ? thank you

Comment: It is possible, from the description you already did it. The open point is who to display the content you or the users want at that address. There are different possibilities, I mentioned some already.

Comment: sorry i am lost, is it possible using .htaccess to accomplish that ? http://example.com/account/user should point to http://user.example.com.. http://user.example.com should display what originally displayed on http://example.com/account/user

Comment: I think you want something like in the example. You may want to strip the `example.com` from the `HTTP_HOST`.

Comment: thank you but this not working... we can rewrite the url of example.com/account/user1 to example.com/account/hellouser1 .. instead of rewriting it to example.com/account/hellouser1 i want to be hellouser1.example.com

Comment: I added an example for that.

Comment: "`RewriteRule /account/(.*)     "http://\1.example.com/"`" - The second argument to the `RewriteRule` directive is a _string_ not a regex. So you need to use the `$1` syntax to refer to the captured group in the `RewriteRule` _pattern_, not the regex-style `\1` as you have used. `\1` is simply an escaped `1`, so you always end up with `1.example.com`.